# Design window not displaying

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm making a windows store application with C# and XAML

I am making a media player application, but I ran into a couple of issues:
- The design form doesn't display my components (I cleaned the solution, I rebuilded the solution, I builded the solution, restarted VS but still it doesn't show anything).

[image]

- Then one of my other components, a slider also doesn't display at runtime.

I am quite new with this so any help will be appreciated.

```
<Page
x:Class="MediaPlayer_LU08_Formative.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MediaPlayer_LU08_Formative"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <AppBar x:Name="TransportControlsPanel" Height="198" Width="1346"      VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="Visible" IsSticky="True" IsOpen="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,10,10">
        <AppBar.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA86E6E" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </AppBar.Background>
        <StackPanel Width="900" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <AppBarButton x:Name="Open" Click="Open_Click_1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Icon="OpenLocal" />
            <Slider x:Name="Vol_Slider" Height="15" Width="112" Value="100" Background="White" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"  Maximum="100" Minimum="0" Visibility="Visible" Margin="394,0"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="84" Margin="0,0,-15,0">
                <AppBarButton x:Name="btnPlay" Click="btnPlay_Click" Icon="Play" />
                <AppBarButton x:Name="btnPause" Click="btnPause_Click" Icon="Pause"/>
                <AppBarButton x:Name="btnStop" Click="btnStop_Click" Icon="Stop" AutomationProperties.Name="Stop"/>
                <AppBarButton x:Name="btnReverse" Click="btnReverse_Click" Icon="Previous"/>
                <AppBarButton x:Name="btnForward" Click="btnForward_Click" Icon="Next"/>
                <AppBarButton x:Name="btnMute" Click="btnMute_Click" Icon="Mute" AutomationProperties.Name="Mute"/>
                <AppBarButton x:Name="btnFullScreenMode" Click="btnFullScreenMode_Click" Icon="FullScreen" AutomationProperties.Name="Full Screen"/>
                <AppBarButton x:Name="DecreaseVolume" Click="DecreaseVolume_Click" Icon="Volume" AutomationProperties.Name="Volume" Content="++"/>
                <AppBarButton x:Name="IncreaseVolume" Click="IncreaseVolume_Click" Icon="Volume" AutomationProperties.Name="Volume" Content="--"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </AppBar>
    <ContentControl x:Name="videoContainer" KeyUp="videoContainer_KeyUp" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="700" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0">
        <MediaElement x:Name="VideoPlayer" AutoPlay="False" Volume="100"/>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to add the namespace of *AppBar* and *AppBarButton* if they exist.

Comment: I got the designer to work but the slider still doesn't show at runtime, design? What is wrong with my code?